opentelemetry java autoconfigure agent: is it possible to send error log lines only?
According to the java agent config here: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/java/configuration/
There is a property to control log exporting (we use new relic via OTLP)
otel.logs.exporter

which has values of otlp, console, logging-otlp, none.
we dont want all the logs being sent from java spring boot app to new relic (as they are far too large), but we do want log.error(xxx) log lines to be exported.  We already have all the logs going into ELK where we can search.
Is there any way to do this?  Ideally what we would want is something like this:
otel.logs.exporter=otlp
otel.logs.exporter.level=error


This should be configured in your logging library. You have to configure your logging library to send logs to OTEL. See https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/java/instrumentation/#logs
